# Adding a condition so the Lebesgue measure of closure is equal to original measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

What assumptions could go in the blank so that this is a theorem? Are there any non-obvious ones?

*Let* $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ *which is measurable and not necessarily closed, and assume* __________________. *Then* 
$$\mathcal{L}^n\left(\overline{A}\right)=\mathcal{L}^n\left({A}\right).$$
(Here $\mathcal{L}^n$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$.)

Comment: Do we have to assume that $A$ is Lebesgue-measurable?

Comment: zhw makes a good point below. Most books only define the Lebesgue-measure on Lebesgue-measurable sets, so we might as well assume measurability.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of an obvious one: Suppose the boundary of $A$ has measure zero. That’s unsatisfying, are there any others?

Comment: I’m actually not sure if this is true if $A$ is non-measurable. Can you think of a counterexample or proof?

Comment: How can you define an integral over $A$ if $A$ is not measurable?

Comment: Ah, that’s a fair point. The book I’m using (Evans and Gariepy) defines the measure of any set as it’s outer measure, so even non-measurable sets have measure. Perhaps it makes sense to just assume $A$ is measurable to avoid confusion over an edge case that probably doesn’t matter.

Comment: When $A$ is open, this obvious condition is necessary and sufficient. So it is unlikely you are going to find something better.

Comment: I think the iff condition is $m(\partial A)=0.$

Comment: @zhw: Or $m(A)=\infty$ :P